# Reversing the bytes in a long in C

Tags: c

Okay, so I'm trying to write a function to reverse a long (64 bytes) in C, and I'm getting some weird results with my bitshifting.

```
long  reverse_long(long x) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
            long a = 0x00000000000000FF<<(8*i);
            long b = 0xFF00000000000000>>(8*i);
            a = x&a;
            b = x&b;

            a=a<<8*(7-2*i);
            b=b>>8*(7-2*i);

            x=x&(~(0x00000000000000FF<<(8*i)));
            x=x&(~(0xFF00000000000000>>(8*i)));
            x=x|a;
            x=x|b;
    }
}
```

On line 4 (`long a = 0x00000000000000FF<<(8*i)`), I'm shifting a byte of ones to the left by 8 bits for each iteration of the loop, which works fine for the first, second, and third iterations, but on the fourth iteration I get something like `0xFFFFFFFF000000`, when I should be getting `0x00000000FF000000`.

Line 5 (`long b = 0x00000000000000FF>>(8*i)`) works just fine though, and gives me the value `0x000000FF00000000`.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: I *think* those are `int` literals. Does it work if you use `0x00000000000000FFL` instead?

Comment: That did work.. I thought adding the L would be redundant since I already declared it as a long. Thanks!

Comment: @statstudent you should post the answer and accept it.

Comment: Hmm...does the signed shift not cause problems? The result of `0xFF000000000000L >> (8 * i)` is implementation-defined (it will be filled with one-bits from the left on today's most common platforms), so I'd expect this to give funny values for, say, `x < 0`.

Comment: You forgot `return x;` at the end

Answer (score 1):

a) Regarding your error:

What you doing there:

```
long a = 0x00000000000000FF<<(8*i);
```

1. Create signed int constant 0xFF;
2. Shit it left by i bytes
3. When it shift by 3 bytes, constant become: 0xFF000000;
4. When it assign it to long signed, performed sign extension:
   0xFF000000 -> 0xFFFFFFFFFF000000;

b) Regarding your code:
There is exist more easy way to write your function, for example:

```
unsigned long reverse_long(unsigned long x) {
  unsigned long rc = 0;
  int i = 8;
  do {
    rc = (rc << 8) | (unsigned char)x;
    x >>= 8;
  } while(--i);
  return rc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand potential problems in your code you need to understand the following things:

1. The type and value of integer literals
2. Rules about left-shifting signed values
3. Rules about right-shifting signed values
4. Rules about `~` on signed values
5. Rules about shifting a value by the width of its type or more
6. The behaviour of out-of-range integral conversions

That's quite a lot of things to remember. To avoid having to deal with all sorts of weird issues (for example, `long a = 0x00000000000000FF<<(8*i);` causes *undefined behaviour* when `i == 3`), I would recommend the following:

- Only use **unsigned** variables and constants (including `x`)
- Use constants which are the correct width for the type

Further, your code makes the assumption that `long` is 64-bit. This is not always true. It would be better to do one of the following two things:

- Have your code work for `unsigned long`, whatever size `unsigned long` might be
- Use `uint64_t` instead of `long`

---

To cut a long story short, this is how your code should look if we just fix errors relating to the points I listed above (and do not change the algorithm):

```
uint64_t reverse_long(uint64_t x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        uint64_t a = 0xFFull << (8*i);
        uint64_t b = 0xFF00000000000000ull >> (8*i);

        a = x&a;
        b = x&b;

        a=a<<8*(7-2*i);
        b=b>>8*(7-2*i);

        x=x&(~(0xFFull<<(8*i)));
        x=x&(~(0xFF00000000000000ull>>(8*i)));
        x=x|a;
        x=x|b;
    }

    return x;   // don't forget this
}
```

note: I have used `ull` suffix to create 64-bit literals. Actually this only guarantees *at least 64 bit*, but since everything is unsigned here it makes no difference, excess bits will just get truncated. To be very precise, write `(uint64_t)0xFF` instead of `0xFFull`, etc.

Comment: Tip: if you give the masks new names then you can re-use them in the `x = x & ~mask;` line , instead of repeating the literal-with-shift.

Answer (score 1):

You've received excellent advice on where you code went awry, but I thought you might like to see an alternate approach to reversing that might be a bit simpler.

```
uint64_t reverse_long(uint64_t n) {
    uint8_t* a = (uint8_t*)&n;
    uint8_t* b = a + 7;
    while(a < b) {
        uint8_t t = *b;
        *b-- = *a;
        *a++ = t;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The right shifting of signed longs is problematic when they're negative.  This minor variant on your code, which is only safe for 64-bit machines where `sizeof(long) == 8)`, ensures that the constants are `long` and the intermediate variables `a` and `b` are `unsigned long` to avoid those problems.  The code contains quite a lot of diagnostics.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long reverse_long(long x);

long reverse_long(long x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("x0 0x%.16lX\n", x);
        unsigned long a = 0x00000000000000FFL << (8 * i);
        unsigned long b = 0xFF00000000000000L >> (8 * i);
        a &= x;
        b &= x;
        printf("a0 0x%.16lX; b0 0x%.16lX\n", a, b);

        a <<= 8 * (7 - 2 * i);
        b >>= 8 * (7 - 2 * i);
        printf("a1 0x%.16lX; b1 0x%.16lX\n", a, b);

        x &= (~(0x00000000000000FFL << (8 * i)));
        x &= (~(0xFF00000000000000L >> (8 * i)));
        printf("x1 0x%.16lX\n", x);
        x |= a | b;
        printf("x2 0x%.16lX\n", x);
    }
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    long x = 0xFEDCBA9876543210L;
    printf("0x%.16lX <=> 0x%.16lX\n", x, reverse_long(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x0 0xFEDCBA9876543210
a0 0x0000000000000010; b0 0xFE00000000000000
a1 0x1000000000000000; b1 0x00000000000000FE
x1 0x00DCBA9876543200
x2 0x10DCBA98765432FE
x0 0x10DCBA98765432FE
a0 0x0000000000003200; b0 0x00DC000000000000
a1 0x0032000000000000; b1 0x000000000000DC00
x1 0x1000BA98765400FE
x2 0x1032BA987654DCFE
x0 0x1032BA987654DCFE
a0 0x0000000000540000; b0 0x0000BA0000000000
a1 0x0000540000000000; b1 0x0000000000BA0000
x1 0x103200987600DCFE
x2 0x1032549876BADCFE
x0 0x1032549876BADCFE
a0 0x0000000076000000; b0 0x0000009800000000
a1 0x0000007600000000; b1 0x0000000098000000
x1 0x1032540000BADCFE
x2 0x1032547698BADCFE
0xFEDCBA9876543210 <=> 0x1032547698BADCFE
```

#### Alternative Implementations

This is a variant of the program above, with the `reverse_long()` changed to `reverse_uint64_v1()` and using `uint64_t` instead of `long` and `unsigned long`.  The printing is upgraded using `PRIX64` format, but also commented out since it is being used in a performance test.  The `reverse_uint64_v2()` function does fewer operations per cycle, though it does more cycles (8 instead of 4).  It copies the low order byte of what's left of the input value into the low order byte of the current output value after it's been shifted left 8 places.  The `reverse_uint64_v3()` function does a loop-unrolling of `reverse_uint64_v2()`, and micro-optimizes by avoiding one assignment to `b` and one extra shift at the end.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "timer.h"

uint64_t reverse_uint64_v1(uint64_t x);
uint64_t reverse_uint64_v2(uint64_t x);
uint64_t reverse_uint64_v3(uint64_t x);

uint64_t reverse_uint64_v1(uint64_t x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        //printf("x0 0x%.16" PRIX64 "\n", x);
        uint64_t a = UINT64_C(0x00000000000000FF) << (8 * i);
        uint64_t b = UINT64_C(0xFF00000000000000) >> (8 * i);
        a &= x;
        b &= x;
        //printf("a0 0x%.16" PRIX64 "; b0 0x%.16" PRIX64 "\n", a, b);

        a <<= 8 * (7 - 2 * i);
        b >>= 8 * (7 - 2 * i);
        //printf("a1 0x%.16" PRIX64 "; b1 0x%.16" PRIX64 "\n", a, b);

        x &= ~(UINT64_C(0x00000000000000FF) << (8 * i));
        x &= ~(UINT64_C(0xFF00000000000000) >> (8 * i));
        //printf("x1 0x%.16" PRIX64 "\n", x);
        x |= a | b;
        //printf("x2 0x%.16" PRIX64 "\n", x);
    }
    return x;
}

uint64_t reverse_uint64_v2(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t r = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(uint64_t); i++)
    {
        uint64_t b = x & 0xFF;
        r = (r << 8) | b;
        x >>= 8;
    }
    return r;
}

uint64_t reverse_uint64_v3(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t b;
    uint64_t r;

    r = x & 0xFF;       // Optimization 1
    x >>= 8;
    b = x & 0xFF;
    r = (r << 8) | b;
    x >>= 8;
    b = x & 0xFF;
    r = (r << 8) | b;
    x >>= 8;
    b = x & 0xFF;
    r = (r << 8) | b;
    x >>= 8;
    b = x & 0xFF;
    r = (r << 8) | b;
    x >>= 8;
    b = x & 0xFF;
    r = (r << 8) | b;
    x >>= 8;
    b = x & 0xFF;
    r = (r << 8) | b;
    x >>= 8;
    b = x & 0xFF;
    r = (r << 8) | b;
    // x >>= 8;         // Optimization 2

    return r;
}

static void timing_test(uint64_t (*reverse)(uint64_t))
{
    Clock clk;
    clk_init(&clk);
    uint64_t ur = 0;
    uint64_t lb = UINT64_C(0x0123456789ABCDEF);
    uint64_t ub = UINT64_C(0xFEDCBA9876543210);
    uint64_t inc = UINT64_C(0x287654321);
    uint64_t cnt = 0;
    clk_start(&clk);
    for (uint64_t u = lb; u < ub; u += inc)
    {
        ur += (*reverse)(u);
        cnt++;
    }
    clk_stop(&clk);
    char buffer[32];
    printf("Sum = 0x%.16" PRIX64 " Count = %" PRId64 " Time = %s\n", ur, cnt,
           clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
}


int main(void)
{
    uint64_t u = UINT64_C(0xFEDCBA9876543210);
    printf("0x%.16" PRIX64 " <=> 0x%.16" PRIX64 "\n", u, reverse_uint64_v1(u));
    printf("0x%.16" PRIX64 " <=> 0x%.16" PRIX64 "\n", u, reverse_uint64_v2(u));
    printf("0x%.16" PRIX64 " <=> 0x%.16" PRIX64 "\n", u, reverse_uint64_v3(u));
    timing_test(reverse_uint64_v1);
    timing_test(reverse_uint64_v2);
    timing_test(reverse_uint64_v3);
    timing_test(reverse_uint64_v1);
    timing_test(reverse_uint64_v2);
    timing_test(reverse_uint64_v3);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
0xFEDCBA9876543210 <=> 0x1032547698BADCFE
0xFEDCBA9876543210 <=> 0x1032547698BADCFE
0xFEDCBA9876543210 <=> 0x1032547698BADCFE
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 8.543540
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 6.822616
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 7.303825
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 8.943668
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 7.314660
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 7.295862
```

The sum and count have two purposes.  First, they provide a cross-check that the results from the three functions are the same.  Second, they ensure that the compiler doesn't do anything like optimize the whole loop out of business.

As you can see, there is not a lot of difference between the `v2` and `v3` timings, but the `v1` code is quite a bit slower than the `v2` or `v3` code.  For clarity, then, I'd use the `v2` code.

For comparison, I also added a 'do nothing' function:

```
uint64_t reverse_uint64_v4(uint64_t x)
{
    return x;
}
```

Clearly, the sum from this is different, but the count is the same, so it measures the overhead of the loop control and counting.  The times I got on two runs were:

```
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 8.965360
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 7.197267
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 7.454553
Sum = 0x09EBA33CFF9869C2 Count = 1683264863 Time = 3.607310
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 8.381292
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 6.804442
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 6.797625
Sum = 0x09EBA33CFF9869C2 Count = 1683264863 Time = 3.541233

Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 8.438374
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 6.805865
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 6.797086
Sum = 0x09EBA33CFF9869C2 Count = 1683264863 Time = 3.532735
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 8.426701
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 6.824182
Sum = 0x0BC6E4692C2EC35A Count = 1683264863 Time = 6.834344
Sum = 0x09EBA33CFF9869C2 Count = 1683264863 Time = 3.510904
```

Clearly, about half the time in the test function is in the loop and function call overhead.